# @ManyToMany not all values obtained from DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have in project user which have authorities. Authorities types stored in database and linked with user as many to many relation.

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_authority", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uauth_user"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uauth_authority"))
private Set<Authority> userAuthorities;
```

But when I try to get all authorities of selected user I obtain just one of them. Hibernate just get first of them and put it to list, but ignore all other authorities of user.

I already check database and it store this data. Also I found solution with adding one not JPA annotations. It works with `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` but I still don't understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: You store your `Set<Authority>` in a Set.
Is it possible that `Authority` are equals to each other?

Comment: No. Authority have simplified compare method by id which unique for all rows in DB.

Comment: It should work. I've just tested your example using EclipseLink and the 2 entity classes User and Authority. How have you defined them? Have you defined also the Entity user_authority (because you have a third column) or not? If yes, how have you defined it?

Comment: An update: I have switched to Hibernate and it works, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem was in different place.

My fault was that when I tried it with Hibernate annotation and it is just works I started thinking that this is an annotation problem, but actually it was caused with method of obtaining this values.

While refactoring we leae in code one mistake:

```
return (T) criteria.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

He we set maximal count of results as 1 and in our case it converted to SQL as

```
SELECT * FROM user OUTER JOIN user_authority ON usr_id = uauth_user INNER JOIN authority ON uauth_authority = auth_id LIMIT 1
```

This limit removes all authorities, and leave just first authority from first line. But when we specify Hibernate FetchMode as SUBSELECT. It execute this get in two separate SQL queries. In which just main have limit.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works on any JPA 2.0 - compliant implementation.

Table `user` has primary key `id`.

Table `authority` has primary key `id`.

Table `user_authority` has fields `user_id`, `authority_id`.

Entity class **User**

```
@JoinTable(name = "user_authority", 
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},  
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Authority> authoritySet;
```

Entity class **Authority**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authoritySet", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> userSet;
```

The Table `user_authority` doesn't have an Entity represention in JPA.